# Questions on Git/Vim interactions

Tags: git, vim, git-interactive-rebase

I have the following screen and need the necessary commands to merge 2 commits.

[image: screenshot of vim running in windows console during an interactive rebase]

Comment: Learn how to use [vim](http://www.vim.org/) or configure `git` to use a different text editor.

Answer (score 2):

You are in the middle of an [**interactive rebase**](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history), and Git has placed you in the [**Vim** editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)) so you can interactively tell Git the actions to take.

You should either learn the basics of Vim, or configure Git to use a different editor.

**But for now**, basically you want to replace the second "pick" with the text "squash" so the two commits are combined into one.

Steps:

- Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to ensure you are in "command mode"
- Press <kbd>j</kbd> to go down to the second line
- Press <kbd>x</kbd> a few times until the "pick" word is removed
- Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter "insert mode" and type the text "squash"
- Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to get out of "insert mode" and back to "command mode"
- Type `:wq` to exit the Vim editor

You have now finished the rebase.

Comment: Command mode is the default. After pressing `j` (or just the "down arrow" cursor key), you can then type `cw` ("change word") to delete "pick" under the cursor and place you in insert mode. Type `s` (no need to type out "squash" in full) and press Esc. Then type `:x` followed by Enter to save and exit.

Comment: Command mode is the default, but it's a good idea to start with an escape just in case the OP had accidentally entered another mode. I considered using `cw` for this, but I wanted to keep things as basic and clear as possible.

Comment: thank you so much :))  I was stuck in that screen for a half an hour but now it works

Answer (score 2):

You should press <kbd>Escape</kbd>, then enter `:cq` (that's <kbd>:</kbd> (colon),
 then <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

Now you will have *left* the vi editor, which is a *fine* editor, but has a bit of a learning curve.

Instead, go install [GitPad](https://github.com/github/GitPad), which will set up notepad as the text editor for Git.

Then you can run your rebase command again and you should be placed in the familiar notepad editor.  (Now, I concede the notepad is a bit of a mediocre editor, but there's no reason to have to learn a decades old Unix text editor while you're trying to learn a merely decade old Unix version control system.) 
 Once notepad opens, follow the instructions that it gives you - in this case, changing the second line from `pick` to `fixup` (or perhaps `squash`) is probably the right thing.